# Ways to solve precendence in parsing algorithms

Tags: python, rust, compiler-construction

I'm studying parsing, more precisely parser combinators and I came across the precedence and associativity problem.

The first solution I found was expressing precedence in the grammar. But this seems to complicate the grammar. Since I'm dealing with parser combinators I expect to express the grammar as function combinations. The first solution I got was something like this

```
expr = or(sequence(int, regex("[+-]"), expr),
          int)
int = regex("\d+")
```

Here `or` and `sequence` emulate `|` and multiple terms in BNF syntax.

_This is very hypothetical, the real source is in Rust [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=818b064dfe9c276f9610c295987642df) if any is interested. My question is much more theoretical... Also [here](https://gist.github.com/dhilst/858244a7f6b06c6929a0b022c362ff53) a more manageable python version _

The other option that I was wondering was. Just parse the input as it is, and then do a second run simplifying it, and by simplify I mean solving the precedence and associative problems too. I didn't find anybody doing this, so I came here.

I was wondering to do something like this, suppose that I parse this input `a * b + c` and output something like this

```
[
  a, 
  Op(*, p=0),
  [
     b,
     Op(+, p=1),
     [
       c
     ]
  ]
]
```

And then use that `p` (from precedence) to create the right tree. Doing this way I can create very declarative grammar like `sum = or(sequence(term, op('+', 1), sum), term)`. My fear is that this become toooo sloooow to run, because of multiple traverses on the tree.

My third idea, and this one I have no clue how to implement in a satisfactory way is to mix both. Keep the combinators but add some simplification logic in the middle of them, in some key points (but in separated functions) that would fix the tree as it is built, I tried something like that to remove terminals and nested sequences.

Is there any other approach that I'm missing? Here is a summarization

1. Express precedence logic in the grammar
2. Generate the whole tree and fix precedence latter
3. Generate partial tree and fix precedence incrementally while the tree is generated

Some questions:

- What approach the big compilers usually take? I know that C takes (1) and python takes something like (1) too.
- Does 2 and 3 have the same computational cost? (to me seems that 3 is lighter because it has to visit less nodes, but my guess is that it would cost as much as 2 in worst cases).

And finally thank you if you read up here.

Comment: You cannot generate a tree without precedence. Precedence can change the structure of the tree

Comment: I can encode the precedence rule in the output and the  generate a tree from then previous one, don't? Or I end up with the same peoblem where I started?

Comment: You can do it in any of those ways, and the one you choose will correspond to your criteria. From what I can see in your question, your criteria seem to mostly revolve around parsing speed; I'd suggest that these days no-one will notice the parsing time unless you use an impossibly inefficient algorithm (exponential backtracking, for example). So you should probably think about how you intend to measure value. I have definite opinions on the subject -- I view a grammar as, first and foremost, documentation -- but those are my opinions, not yours, and they apparently have no place here.

Comment: To answer your question "What do the other guys do?": if the language has fixed precedence and associativity, the usual thing is to put it into the grammar. But some languages allow programs to define new operators, so the precedence and associativity are not fixed. In that case, you have to fix the tree after the declarations are known, which might not have happened when the operators are first seen. There are well-known algorithms for that, and a few tree rotations will not have an exorbitant cost.

Comment: Hi rici, I'm planning to write a parser for sml, which has arbitrary infix operator but there is a long road down there. I really didn't understand how associativity is fixed in the grammar, precedence is okay. Also not having a lexer seems to complicate things a bit

Comment: Rici did you know any material that I can use on expressing precedence and associativity on the grammar?

Comment: @geckos: "associativity" is an approximate description of a grammar (as is "precedence"); real grammars are much more flexible than those terms would indicate. In a context-free expression grammar, a left-associative operator generally corresponds to a left-recursive rule and a right-associative operator to a right-recursive rule. Most operators are left-associative. If you're using a formalism which requires top-down parsing, then left-recursion might not be available to you. (You're literally parsing with one hand tied behind your back.) That makes tree-rotation your only option...

Comment: ... But, as you say, SML allows operator declarations, so it doesn't really matter: your best bet is to just handle parentheses during the initial parse and reanalyse operator tree nodes once you have all the declarations available. You can use a simplified version of the operator precedence algorithm (aka "shunting yard") to apply precedence and associativity. That's easy to search for.

Comment: Thank you so much rici. Now I understand my problem. I was mixing up parser algorithm and grammar. My confusion started because I was trying to generate left associativity on recursive descendant parser, and got stuck. Summing up I need to choose a bottom up parser or do tree rotations, there isn't much what to do beside that. Thank you again!

Comment: I personally prefer 3, using the [Shunting Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)